# Using jQuery and Ajax to capture and send parameters in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've the following `HTML` link code

```
<div id="message"></div>
<a href="cats.php?id=60&color=brown&name=kitty" id="petlink">
Click here
</a>
```

using `jQuery` and `Ajax` and On click this link, I would like to send those parameters

```
id=60
color=brown
name=kitty
```

to a file `find.php` that will catch those parameters using `$_GET` as

```
<?PHP
    $id    = $_GET['id'];     // 60
    $color = $_GET['color']; // brown
    $name  = $_GET['name']; // kitty

// doing some searching in database

echo "yep found it"; // or whatever i would print
?>
```

and will respond back with whatever (like `echo "yep found it"`) that would be shown up in between this `div`
 `<div id="message"></div>`

I've read many tutorials but all was speaking about form data submissions but unfortunately i did not found for such case so any help will really appropriate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create this you simply need to send an AJAX request from the `click` event of the `a` element. You can retrieve the querystring by reading the `src` property of the anchor, something like this:

```js
$('#petlink').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'find.php',
    data: this.src.split('?')[1],
    success: function(response) {
      $('#message').text(response);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: One think that I would add is to take the `url` from the `anchor` and put it on the `url` property of of the `ajax` call ;)

Comment: @DragosRizescu they are different.

Comment: thanks a lot, I've never knew i can do this `data: this.src.split('?')[1]` but now I've learned something very useful.

Answer (score 1):

as rory sad you need to give a click event to your a tag then

```
$('#petlink').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
  type:'POST'
  url: 'find.php&pets=1',
  data: this.href.split('?')[1],
dataType:'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $('#message').text(response);
   }
  });
 });
```

on your php file just add

if($_GET['pets'] == 1)
   {

```
 $id    = $_POST['id'];     // 60
  $color = $_POST['color']; // brown
  $name  = $_POST['name']; // kitty
  echo 'pets came';
  exit;
```

}

Comment: What's the purpose of adding the `pets` argument? Also, both you and the OP are returning a plain text response, not JSON.

Comment: pets=1 is for afirmating your request if you want you can just do like if($_GET['id']>0) and for json you need to add echo json_encode('pets came');